# issue when installing bower uid must be an unsigned int

Tags: node.js, git, npm, bower, osx-elcapitan

Thanks in advance

I have a problem installing bower it says:

```
MYNAME-MacBook-Pro:~ MYNAME$ sudo chown -R $(MYNAME) ~/.npm
-bash: MYNAME: command not found
usage: chown [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] owner[:group] file ...
       chown [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] :group file ...
Rogers-MacBook-Pro:~ MYNAME$ sudo npm install bower -g
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "bower" "-g"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! uid must be an unsigned int
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/MYNAME/npm-debug.log}
```

I search already but I cannot fix it .--- MacBook pro EL CAPITAN 10.11.6---

Answer (score 0):

The error says all.

You have `$(MYNAME)` in your script, this starts a subshell and tries to execute the command `MYNAME`. This results in the shown first error `-bash: MYNAME: command not found` and the result of the subshell is empty.

As you do not have your subshell call in doublequotes, it is not considered as empty argument, but in your case `~/.npm` is taken as second argument of chown and the third argument is missing, hence the usage message of chown which is shown.

So your first command did not have any effect because it is totally broken. Fix it and I guess the bower install also will work.